# AMI to pine conversion

Tags: pine-script

I am converting a code from AMIbroker to pinescript, just wanted to ask if the method used is correct here and does the same since pine does not have REF keyword in there programming coding manual so I have used nz here.

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")

/////////PINE CODE///// 
AOFast  = sma(( high + low ) / 2, 5 )
AOSlow  = sma(( high + low ) / 2, 34)
AO      = AOFast - AOSlow
UB      = AO > nz(AO[1], -1)
DB      = AO < nz(AO[1], -1)
aColor = UB ? color.green  : DB ? color.red   : color.orange
plot( AO , "AO", color=aColor ,  style=plot.style_histogram , linewidth=1)
```

---

AMIbroker code

```
AOFast  = MA( ( H + L ) / 2, 5 );
AOSlow  = MA( ( H + L ) / 2, 34 );
AO      = AOFast - AOSlow;
UB      = AO > Ref( AO, -1 );
DB      = AO < Ref( AO, -1 );
ClrBar  = IIf( UB, ParamColor( "AO Up", colorGreen ), IIf( DB, ParamColor( "AO Down", colorRed ), colorGrey40 ) );
Plot( AO, "AO", ClrBar, styleHistogram );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AO[1]` in pine is equivalent to `Ref(AO, -1)` in Amibroker

There is code for the built in Awesome Oscillator indicator available in pine under the "Open" menu and under "New default built-in script" in the script editor